# whats the solution of ubuntu software center

Tags: system-installation

I tried installing VLC Player yesterday, and I got the Requires installation of untrusted packages error. I searched for hours for a solution to this problem whats the solution? pleas

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install vlc` from a Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it from the command-line and tell us what happens.
First add the ppa by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily

sudo apt-get update
```

Now install vlc:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: thanks... but the solution founded sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update